# How to convert from binary to decimal in LBPH algorithm (face recognition )?

Tags: opencv, face-recognition, lbph-algorithm

I have a problem in understanding the transformation of the spid window in the lbph algorithm , exactly in the part of from a binary to a decimal [image]

how we can know that we have the values 150 , 90 ... 
im which direction the window binary been reading ?

Comment: didnt check it, but isnt 10001101 the value 141 and the LBP 9x9 block is only the central value of the result? The neighbors have their own binary field/value/block

Comment: to know where the values 150, 90, 80, 30 come from.you'll need to know all the 8 neighbors of the input values at that pixel position.

Comment: How can i know that ?

Comment: the binary values are read row-wise. E.g. the binary of result value 150 is 10010110,  this means the top-left neighbor of the 200-pixel must be bigger than 200, the top-val is smaller, the top-right is smaller, the left is bigger, the right is smaller (it is 50), the bottom-left is bigger, the bottom is bigger (must be an error in the example, since the bottom is 50) and the bottom-right is smaller (90)